# How to prevent ng-click in container not be triggered by elements inside in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this situation:

```
<div ng-click="foo()">
  <a ng-click="bar()">Bar</a>
  <p>Lorem Ipsun</p>
</div>
```

My problem is, when I click in Bar, foo() is called too. How to call just bar() when click in Bar, and just call foo() when I am not click in bar()?

Answer (score 3):

I got my answer in this question:

[AngularJS ng-click stopPropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation)

Just need to change the HTML to this:

```
<div ng-click="foo()">
  <a ng-click="bar(); $event.stopPropagation()">Bar</a>
  <p>Lorem Ipsun</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ngClick` provides the event object in a `$event` variable. You can call `stopPropagation()` on it to stop the event from bubbling...

```
<div ng-click="foo()">
  <a ng-click="bar($event)">Bar</a>
  <p>Lorem Ipsun</p>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.bar = function ($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k4LaJ/)

Comment: Do you think that put <a ng-click="bar(); $event.stopPropagation()"> could be more faster about performance than pass $event as argument? Also, if in other part I would call bar(), I don't need always to pass $event. What do you think?

Comment: Perf-wise, you would never notice the difference. But now that I think about it, this is a view-specific concern and the controller method shouldn't know about it, you should use `ng-click="bar(); $event.stopPropagation()"`. +1 for your answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use event.stopPropation() or event.cancelBubble = true to prevent event bubbling
Write this code inside the bar() method to prevent calling foo() (parent) method

```
event = event || window.event // cross-browser event
  if (event.stopPropagation) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    event.cancelBubble = true;
  }
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/55sfc/1/