# ng-click event gets bind to child li in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, haml, angularjs-ng-click

Hey I am binding menuIconClick($event) function on li using ng-click directive.But gets bind to child li also.
Code like as follow

```
%div.sideNavBar
  %ul.navBar
    %li.icons-briefcase-static{'ng-click'=>"menuIconClick($event)"} // binding here only
      %ul.subMenu
        %li All sites // but gets call here also
        %li{'ng-repeat'=>"site in sites"}
          {{site.name}}
    %li.icons-users-disabled
  %div.lock.icons-lock-disabled
```

The template is in HAML.
I didn't got why?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Is it just because one `<li>` is inside the other, so the click event "bubbles" up the hierarchy?

Comment: @chandu sorry no code fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the icon & icon click event as a separate element, not on the parent element.  DOM events bubble up the hierarchy, so if the parent element has an `ng-click` handler, then clicking any child element will also trigger that parent click handler unless you stop the event propagation.

You could either stop the event propagation, similar to:

[AngularJS ng-click stopPropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation)

or change your DOM structure so that the briefcase icon is not a parent of the submenu:

```
%div.sideNavBar
  %ul.navBar
    %li
      %a.icons-briefcase-static{'ng-click'=>"menuIconClick($event)"} // no longer a parent
      %ul.subMenu
        %li All sites // click here won't bubble up to ng-click
        %li{'ng-repeat'=>"site in sites"}
          {{site.name}}
    %li.icons-users-disabled
  %div.lock.icons-lock-disabled
```

Comment: Thank you for response.I can not change the structure but when I am using stopPropagation then It is not working for me.

Comment: Are you using stopPropagation on the child?  Not on the parent like @chandu shows?

Comment: I have given it like chandu mentioned =>

%li.icons-briefcase-static{'ng-click'=>"menuIconClick($event); $event.stopPropagation();"}

Comment: Yeah that won't do anything for you.  You want to call stopPropagation on the child element. `%li{'ng-click'=>'$event.stopPropagation();'} All Sites`

Answer (score 1):

Try his one. `e.stopPropagation()` I am not sure about this.

```
%li.icons-briefcase-static{'ng-click'=>"menuIconClick($event);$event.stopPropagation();"}
```

Comment: I have given $event.stopPropagation(); But still that function is getting called on child li click.

Comment: can you try with ng-click-active="$first".

Comment: This totally did it for me. Stopped other click events set on parent tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In html list,
```

ng-click="menuIconClick($event)"

```
 In JS function,
```

$scope.menuIconClick = function(ev){

```
ev.stopPropagation();
```

}