# Element and its parent have an ng-click specified, both are called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a `DIV` with a function specified to be called when clicked on it by `ng-click`.

Inside this `DIV` there's a `BUTTON` which also have a function to be called when clicked on, specified by `ng-click`.

When I click the button, both the `DIV`'s click and the `BUTTON`'s click functions are called.
How do I make that only the `BUTTON`'s function is called?

I have set up this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cj5rc6h2/1/) for better illustrate what I mean. Below is the code:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="Test">
    <section ng-controller="TestCtrl as ctrl">
        <div class="square" ng-click="ctrl.divClick()">
            <span>My text</span>
            <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClick()" >My button</button>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('Test', []);

    app.controller('TestCtrl', [function() {
        this.divClick = function() {
            alert('div clicked');            
        };

        this.buttonClick = function() {
            alert('button clicked');
        }
    }]);
})();
```

**EDIT**:

As suggested by [akonsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410102/akonsu), I just need to stop the event propagation. This worked for me.
Here's an updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cj5rc6h2/2/) showing how it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-click stopPropagation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stop propagation of the event:

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClick($event)">

this.buttonClick = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('button clicked');
}
```

Comment: Wow that was simpler than I expected. Thanks, I'll update my question and Fiddle with your suggestion.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to show this but you beat me to it, http://jsfiddle.net/cj5rc6h2/3/ @BrunoFinger, don't forget to accept akonsu's answer