# ng-click on current tag

Tags: css, angularjs, background, angularjs-ng-click

I have general container which is full screen background and inside it i have small div with content. In general container i have ng-click which activated when i click on small div. How can i disable that?

```
<div class="generalContainer" ng-click="onlyBackground()">
    <div class="smallDiv">Content</div>
</div>
```

I have tried to add `z-index` on background and small div, but still function activated on small div. I am not sure if it's css matter or angular.

Comment: Take a look at stopping click propagation in your small div by adding an `ng-click` handler and calling `$event.stopPropagation()` in the handler. Similiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation

Comment: yeah, that same problem with the url you gave, couldn't find it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having child in dom, would affect parent element ng-click. 
This is because events go up in Dom tree. You can ommit it, by forcing to stop propagation: 
Use:

```
<div class="generalContainer" ng-click="onlyBackground()">
    <div class="smallDiv" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">Content</div>
</div>
```

When you click on `smallDiv`, then click want propagate into parent.

Answer (score 1):

Does your element has a position property? z-index only works if the the element has a position property.

```
.generalContainer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.smallDiv {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: generalContainer  is absolute, smallDiv is relative

Comment: try to add to both of them the property clear:both. if that's not working try adding overflow:hidden.

Comment: people suggest other angular solution and it work, thank you for helping