# How to prevent a ng-click event on a div in a sub controller from triggering an ng-click in the root?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

**http://plnkr.co/edit/gB7MtVOOHH0FBJYa6P8t?p=preview**

[image]

I have a parent child controller example above, in the child when a button is clicked I displays the div `showPop` and then will `$emit` an event upwards to the `$rootScope`.

Now in the parent / `$rootScope` I "hear" that event then activate another function.

That function in the `$rootScope` triggers the `bodyClick` click function to be active, so once a click is registered in the body/parent/rootScope the div `showPop` is now hidden.

The problem is that while I want clicks on the body to close that div out, I do NOT want clicks on the actual div itself to trigger it to close?

How could I accomplish this / work around the `$rootScope` ng-click event?

```
.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
                              function($scope,$rootScope) {

  var unbind = $rootScope.$on('popoverOpen');

  $scope.$on('popoverOpen', function(events, data) {
    console.log('popoverOpen is heard!')
    $scope.bodyClick = function() {
        console.log('bodyClick sent down from main');
        $scope.theAction = 'bodyClick sent down from main';
        $rootScope.$broadcast('bodyClick');
    };

    $scope.$on('$destroy', unbind);
  });
}])

.controller('subController', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
                             function($scope, $rootScope) {

  $scope.callPop = function($event) {
    $rootScope.theAction = 'popoverOpen emitted up from sub';
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.showPop = true;
    $scope.$emit('popoverOpen');
  };

  $scope.$on('bodyClick', function() {

    console.log('bodyClick received in sub!');
    $rootScope.theAction = 'bodyClick received in sub!';
    $scope.showPop = false;
    $scope.$emit('destroy');
  });
}]);
```

Markup:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController" ng-click="bodyClick()">

<h1>mainController</h1>

<div class="sidebar" ng-controller="subController">
  <h2>subController</h2>
  <button ng-click="callPop($event)">Click Me</button>

  <div ng-show="showPop" class="pop-box">This is showPop, clicking in here should not close it, clicking outside should!</div>
</div>

<section class="the-section">
  {{theAction}}
</section>

</body>
```

Comment: If you don't want a click on the body. Why don't you try something with an overlay ? A click on the overlay close the pop and also prevent the click to go further ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation

Comment: @Okazari ah true! So I guess hmm... yeah I can have another directive element under all my popovers to handle that... lol I guess I was making things too hard.

Comment: @DRobinson I'm using stop propagation now, it prevents the click on the sub to act as a click on the body as well. Problem is after the event has been activated, the click on the body will now always get registered first before the sub.

Comment: @Okazari do you want to post the answer? I don't have to try find a more complex way to do this... an overlay directive with it's own scope fixes this!

Comment: angular.module('app').directive('overlayEvent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, el) {
      el.on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
      });
    }
  }

Comment: I am learning custom directive and thanks to @Okazari for the guides which help me come up with the code above :D

Comment: Wich guides helped you ? I'm proud my posts helped some people :)

Comment: @Okazari: clicking on the overlay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something with an overlay. A click on the overlay close the pop and also prevent the click to go further.

Glad this suggestion helped you.