# How to prevent $event fo fire twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a table component in AngularJS but i'm having a bug that i can't solve.

The structure of my table is something like:

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-click="selectRow()" ng-repeat="$value in values track by $index" ng-click="selectRow($index,$value)>
       <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="$value.__checked"  ng-click="selectRow($index,$value)"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When i click on the row, it works fine, but when i click on the checkbox it doesn't work as expected, and fire the event twice. I thought that just using the stopPropagation() on `selectRow` when it's fired by the checkbox would work, but it doesn't.

The function selectRow can work for multi and single seleciton.

```
function selectRow(ngRepeatIndex,ngRepeatValue){
    var selectedValues = $scope.$parent.selectedValues;
    cleanValueAndArrays(vm.checkAll,vm.checkAll);
    if($attrs.onClick)vm.onClick({value: ngRepeatValue});
    if(vm.config.selection == 'single'){
      if(ngRepeatValue.__checked){
        ngRepeatValue.__checked = false;
        cleanArrays();
      } else {
        cleanValueAndArrays(vm.selectedIndexes.length > 0)
        pushToArrays(ngRepeatValue,ngRepeatIndex);
        ngRepeatValue.__checked = true;
      }
    } else {
      ngRepeatValue.__checked = vm.selectedIndexes.filter(function(val){return val == ngRepeatIndex}).length < 1;
      if((ngRepeatValue.__checked) || vm.selectedIndexes.length == 0 ){
        pushToArrays(ngRepeatValue,ngRepeatIndex);
        return 0;
      }
      var indexOfValueSelected;
      selectedValues.forEach(function(val,indx){
        if(angular.equals(val,ngRepeatValue)) indexOfValueSelected = indx;
      })
      $scope.$parent.selectedValues.splice(indexOfValueSelected, 1);
      vm.selectedIndexes.splice(vm.selectedIndexes.indexOf(ngRepeatIndex),1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-click stopPropagation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation)

Comment: Why don't you remove the second ng-click ? it is useless, the ng-click on the row will be called if you click on your checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second ng-click, it is useless, the ng-click on the row will be called if you click on your checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive to stop event propagation.

```
moduleName.directive('preventDefault', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
```

You can use it as below:

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="$value in values track by $index" ng-click="selectRow($index,$value) prevent-default>
       <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="$value.__checked"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-click="selectRow()" ng-repeat="$value in values track by $index" ng-click="selectRow($index,$value)>
       <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="$value.__checked"  ng-click="selectRow($index,$value); $event.stopPropagation();"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```