# ng-click triggered twice with in a nested ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have an issue when trying to use the `ng-click` inside a list which is a sub list of another list which has a `ng-click` event. Following is my code

```
<ul>
  <li
    ng-repeat="facet in node.Facets"
    ng-click="updateNav(facet.Action)"
    ng-cloak
   >
    {{facet.DisplayValue}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="sub in facet.Refinements.Nodes[0].Facets"
        ng-click="updateSubNav(sub.Action)"
      >
        {{sub.DisplayValue}}
      </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem I have is, when I click `updateSubNav` it automatically triggers `updateNav`. How can I prevent triggering `updateNav` When I click `updateSubNav` (because I want those 2 methods to work independently?

Comment: The answer may be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prevent the event propagation.

**View:**

```
<li ng-repeat="sub in facet.Refinements.Nodes[0].Facets"
    ng-click="updateSubNav($event, sub.Action)">
                           ^^^^^^        === Pass event object
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.updateSubNav = function($event, action) {
    // Code here

    // Stop propagation
    $event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how event bubbling works, You need to `stopPropagation` of inner div click event to prevent to happen it upwards.

```
ng-click="updateSubNav(sub.Action); $event.stopPropagation()"
```

You could do the same by passing `$event` object to `updateSubNav` method & `stopPropagation` of event from there like `@Tushar` already shown in his answer.

Comment: @sameera207 np, I pleased that you got helped from us, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to event bubbling

```
 <ul>
          <li
            ng-repeat="facet in node.Facets"
            ng-click="updateNav(facet.Action)"
            ng-cloak
           >
            {{facet.DisplayValue}}
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="sub in facet.Refinements.Nodes[0].Facets"
                ng-click="updateSubNav(sub.Action, $event)"
              >
                {{sub.DisplayValue}}
              </li>
             </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>


        $scope.updateSubNav = function(action,$event){
         $event.stopPropagation();
        }
```