# stopPropogation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using panel bootstrap accordion.

When we click anywhere, on panel head will collapse panel body 
but there is one inline span element with click event
so,i need to prevent `collapse in` class of panel body and i need to trigger span click event.

my approach:

for this,
I used `$event.stopPropogation()`

**html**

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
  <div class="panel" ng-repeat="uniqueId in uniqueIds">
    <div class="panel panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" data-target="#{{uniqueId}}">
      <span>{{uniqueId}}</span>
      <span class="pull-right" ng-click="fnShowJdTrack()">Track JD</span>
    </div>
    <div id="{{uniqueId}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <!--  content here  -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ctrl**

```js
$scope.fnShowJdTrack = function() {
  $event.stopPropagation();
  //some other action here
};
```

Comment: Add event in your function! function(event)

Comment: function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    };

Comment: I tried that way its not working :(

Comment: try stopImmediatePropagation instead of stopPropagation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `$event` object to the function.

```
<span class="pull-right" ng-click="fnShowJdTrack($event)">Track JD</span>
```

And in your controller:

```js
$scope.fnShowJdTrack = function($event) {
  $event.stopPropagation();
  //some other action here
};
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20301030/863110

For example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.stop = true;
  
  $scope.outerClick = function(){
    alert('outer');
  };

  $scope.innerClick = function($event) {
    if ($scope.stop) {
      $event.stopPropagation();
    }
    alert('inner');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="stop" /> stopPropagation</label>
  <div ng-click="
outerClick()">
    <div ng-click="innerClick($event)">Inner div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. You have to pass the `$event` exactly string. You can pass both of them: `fnShowJdTrack('show.bs.collapse', $event)`. Also, `show.bs.collapse` is not an `event` object. Is suppose to be a string and bootstrap. Let it go, bro it's not relevant.. Just pass the `$event` object as is.