# AngulaJs: ng-click not work on netsted uib-accordion

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion, angularjs-ng-click

I use `nested uib-accordion`, and I want add `ng-click` to each of uib-accordion.

```
      <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime1">
            <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="prInfo.isOpen" heading="{{prInfo.name}}"
                 ng-click="getPayrolls(prInfo)"
                 ng-repeat="prInfo in allPersonInfoNames">
                <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime2">
                    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="{{payroll.logPeriod.name}}"
                         ng-click="getPayroll(payroll)"
                         ng-repeat="payroll in prInfo.payrolls | orderBy: 'logPeriod.dbId': reverse = true">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h1>in nested accordion</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </uib-accordion>
            </div>
        </uib-accordion>
```

So, when I click on first accordion, **first ng-click work correctly**, but when I click on second accordion, again first `ng-click` is called, and second ng-click never called.

I can solve this problem by adding second `ng-click` in body of accordion, 
but by this solution, I have to click 3 times to work second ng-click, first time for open the first accordion and run first `ng-click`, second time to open second accordion and third time click on function in nested accordion body to run second `ng-click`. How can I separate `ng-click functions` by first solution?

[demo on plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YBC1VftQEBHmpK1uK9Z4?p=preview)

Comment: In your plunkr this line is causing an error.   $scope.allPersonInfoNames[1].payrolls.push({deposit: 999999}) because $scope.allPersonInfoNames[1] has no key payrolls.

Comment: The problem is fixed, but now when I click on second ng-click, two functions called again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem your facing seems to be related to this thread: [AngularJS ng-click stopPropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation) 
When you click on the second ng-click, you have to stop the event propagation to prevent the first method to be triggered.

I Hope it may help