# Do not trigger ng-click of parent element when clicking wrapped checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, event-propagation

In AngularJS I have a table row with a `ng-click` attribute. It is used to bring up a dialog with detailed information about the table item. Furthermore, each table row has a checkbox to select the item for batch processing (e.g. deletion).

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items..." href="#detailDialog"
    data-toggle="modal" ng-click="openDialog(...)">
  <td style="text-align: center;">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" />
  </td>
  <td>{{ item.foo }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.bar }}</td>
</tr>
```

However, when I click on the checkbox, the `ng-click` event of the parent table row is also triggered. How do I prevent this from happening? I only want to open the dialog, when the user clicks a table row but not the checkbox.

Is there any option other than binding the `ng-click` to individual cells?

Comment: Check this out! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need an ng-click on your checkbox input that you could then apply $event.stopPropogation to keep the click event from bubbling up to the row. You'll have to test, but I think that may be what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!