# Ionic 3 Nav push: with $event.Stoppropagation() is not working in ion-card with nested (click)

Tags: angular, ionic3, stoppropagation

I have found some examples. no results:

> [AngularJS ng-click stopPropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation)
>
> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-how-to-use-event-preventdefault/56257/7

I have created a card list layout and clickable on card as well as a link within the card. I want to use nested click items within the card. But when I click on link in the card its opening the card details instead going to the link page.

I am using NavController with NavParams to navigate from card link to another modal/view.

Note: I have imported all the required built in components

```
<ion-card (click)="open(this.item)">
<span>Ticket 1<span>
<a (click)="viewMore($event , this.item);">View More</a>
</ion-card>

<!-- angular component method--->
viewMore(event: Event, item:any): void{
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(item);
    this.navCtrl.push(TicketDetailsPage, { item: item });
}
```