# After if statement is satisfied else part is also being executed in IE (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom-events

I want to stop event bubbling so I am using `$event.stopPropagation()`, it is working in all browsers except IE+9 (any version it is not working). I have a div (tile) and switch toggle button inside that. When I click on the tile then a pop-up opens and also another pop up opens on click of the switch toggle button. It is working fine when the tile is clicked i.e., only that pop-up is getting opened but when I click on switch toggle button then tile's open pop-up and switch button pop up opens. Please find the code below

I have tried using `$event.preventDefault()` and `if($event.stopPropagation){ event = event || $window.event } else { this.$window.cancelBubble = true };`

```
<div class="tile"
     data-ng-click="controller.openPopup()">
    <div class="tile-header">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label form-check-toggle" ng-click="controller.activateTrigger(controller.myVariable, $event); $event.stopPropagation();">
                    <input class="form-check-input"
                           checked="true"
                           type="checkbox"
                           ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    />
                    <span></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile-body">
        Tile body
    </div>

</div>
```

In IE, I just want the switch button's pop-up to open when the switch button is clicked.

**Update**: I added `$event.stopPropagation();` to my label then it was working but I added an else part in my `controller.activateTrigger()` function then I am getting the same problem again. When I click on the input, first parent div's pop up is getting opened and then label's pop up is opening. In the else part I am calling the same function as in parent div `contoller.openPopup()`.

JS:

```
activateTrigger(myVariable, $event) {
    if(myVariable) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // when my variable is false
        // when variale is true then this part is also getting executed in IE
        this.openPopup();
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the previous answers helped me! I am asking for a solution for IE9+ browsers not lesser than that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation solved my issue.